# How to automatically logout multiple devices with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, logout

I am using Laravel 9 and I want to log a user out automatically (without refresh) if they try to log in through multiple devices.
I am using the the following code (inside the **loginController.php**) and it works but the user needs to refresh in order to get logged out:

```
protected function authenticated()
    {
        Auth::logoutOtherDevices(request('password'));
    }
```

Is there any way to automaticall log the user out at multiple login (without refresh) ? .. I am thinking about Ajax ? events ? .

Thanks

Comment: If you are using any real time communication, you can send a event through it. Otherwise you can set a timer to refresh the page automatically if it's idle for some time.

Comment: the page is video playlist (has lessons) and I don't think its a good idea to refresh it .. and I am using laravel with bootstrap only (not vue or react or inertia) ..

Comment: Then I think you can use socket, check for login status and send an event through socket. It'll use less bandwidth.

Comment: can you please share a link (tutorial/article) with me ?

Comment: You could create a client side function to post a request to process an Auth check every 60 seconds. If auth fails then refresh page (which should show logged out).

Comment: @AnthonyBird Thanks, I would use AJAX for this .. but won't this affect the performance? and also, if a user disables javascript, it would stop working right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a websockets infrastructure set up on this site, then I agree that's the easiest method. Otherwise it's overkill for such a simple task.

Set up a route like this:

```php
Route::get("/auth/check", fn () => Auth::check ? response("ok") : response("fail", 401))->name("auth.check");
```

This will return a 401 error code is the user isn't authenticated.

Then on the client side (I'm assuming you're in a Blade template here) do something like this:

```js
const authCheck = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: @json(route("auth.check")),
        error: function(xhr) {
            if (xhr.status === 401) {
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
}

// run it every 60 seconds
setInterval(authCheck, 60000);
```

This just defines a function that calls your new route. If it fails due to an authentication error, it reloads the page. This will allow Laravel to redirect the user to the login page.

---

If you're not using jQuery, your script might look like this:

```js
const authCheck = function() {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 401) {
            location.reload();
        }
    }
    xhr.open("GET", @json(route("auth.check")));
    xhr.send();
}

setInterval(authCheck, 60000);
```

---

No, none of this will work if the client has Javascript disabled; nor will websockets. If you want to work on the client side, you are at the mercy of the client.

Comment: this is completely convincing, I will implement that now .. but one last question: is it bad for performance to keep sending requests at each (n) period of time ?

Comment: I can't imagine how it would be. Web browsers' sole purpose is to send requests, so they are pretty good at doing it. And it's not like you're doing a lot of computational work with the response.

Comment: sure will do :)

Comment: Worked elegantly :) .. not only that.. but you gave me more information .. Thank you forever

Comment: one final thing Mike, at the next login (after the user gets logged out) when I sign in again it takes me to auth/check page which is not preferred to happen .. 
what should be done here ?

Comment: Yes I guess default after login is to redirect to originally requested page. Instead of your script doing a redirect to login, maybe just refresh the page? Laravel should do the redirect to login and then return them to the same page after logging in.

Comment: yesssss .. replaced it with 
location.reload( ) ,, works as expected ..... <3

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do this using websockets. You can use Laravel Echo for this,  and create a broadcast event called something like `RefreshBrowser`.

Then in your Javascript, you'd listen for the event and trigger a browser refresh via JS when that event is called.

Comment: You wouldn't have to. No reason you couldn't have a simple Ajax check on a `setTimeout` loop.

Comment: @miken32 Adding client-side AJAX request polling to every single user for something that is probably an infrequent occurrence is a bad idea.

Comment: @kjoedion why is it a bad idea to use AJAX ? 
can you share a link or a tutorial about using websockets with laravel ?

Comment: @miken32 thanks, this is what I thought about .. but send a request to what ? what page?

Comment: @miken32 so, I make a php file that checks only for Auth::check( ) , and send ajax request from client to it, if true (logged in) then do nothing, else, log the user out (with Javascript) or just refresh.. correct ?